# Monitor ASP.NET CORE thread pool starvation

Tags: c#, multithreading, amazon-ec2, async-await

We had a situation before a few days where our AWS EC2 instances where running out of threads( Thread pool starvation) with a heavy load of traffic because of one mistake with async missing in one of the method. Is that possible to detect or avoid this situation before we go live? Basically, I want the way to monitor if this situation arises we get some kind of notification. May be by health check etc.

Comment: unit test / functionally test your code before deploying it

Comment: Is there a way we can detect thread pool starvation by unit testing the API call?